# Как задеплоить quasar android приложение

Tags: vue.js, cordova

Только начал изучать cordova/vue/quasar.
Хочу сделать простое приложение. Понимаю, что должен генериться .apk, который в итоге должен стучаться на какой-то url. Оттуда уже и тянуть всю верстку и инфу. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Делаю все по инструкции quasar.
В итоге подключаю свой android-смартфон по usb, выполняю:

```
quasar dev -m cordova -T android
```

и локально все вижу.

Но как сделать так, чтобы это все можно было явить миру, то есть имея доступ в интернет запустить это приложение, которое сходит на хостинг и вернет готовый результат?

Comment: Тут детально описано.
[Build an Android App with Quasar Framework](https://codeburst.io/build-an-android-app-with-quasar-framework-f3008f02374)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ собрать APK и залить вручную.

Проверяем свежесть сборки.

```
$ quasar build
```

Заварачиваем эту сборку с Cordova:

```
$ quasar wrap cordova
$ cd cordova
```

Затем добавляем Android в список платформ:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

Проверяем, что Cordova по-прежнему настроена корректно:

```
$ cordova requirements
```

После того, как все это подтвердится, вы можете создать файл Android APK:

```
$ cordova build --release
```

Answer (score -1):

Если выполнили все инструкции подготовки приложения и веб работает нормально, делаем следующее:

1. Сделать сборку приложения

   quasar build -m cordova -T android

Если по какой то причине сборка не происходит, один из советов переустановит набор утилит для андроид

```
quasar mode remove cordova
cordova platform remove android
quasar mode add cordova
npm install -g cordova-android
cd src-cordova
cordova platform add android
```

2. Если сборка прошла успешна, искать результат в
   dist/cordova/android/bundle/release/app-release.aab

**app-release.aab** - и есть результирующий файл по новым правилам.

3. Чтобы с него получить APK делаем следующее:

   java -jar bundletool.jar build-apks --bundle=app-release.aab --output=app-release.apks
4. app-release.apks переименовать в app-release.zip и распаковать архив. Внутри находим файлы base-master.apk или base-master_2.apk
   Это и есть файлы для установки. Но !!!
   Они не установятся в систему т.к. не имеют подписей.
5. Формируем файлы для подписи:

   keytool -genkey -v -keystore lcf.keystore -alias lcf -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
6. Подписываем файл APK

   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore lcf.keystore base-master.apk lcf

   apksigner sign --ks lcf.keystore --ks-key-alias lcf base-master.apk

Обратите внимание, нужно сделать две подписи.
APK готов для установки. Разрешите на своем устройстве установку из сторонних источников.
Если что будет ругаться на отсутствие утилит, версий java, JDK и т.д. тут уже все зависит от вашей системы и это отдельные поиски.
Good Luck !!!